# Shorthand for using multiple names from the same C++ namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, shorthand, abbreviation

I'm writing a chess program and I've defined the classes I've created under the `chess` namespace.

To shorten the code in files that use those classes, I preface it with `using chess::Point, chess::Board, chess::Piece` and so on.

Is there a way to specify that I'm bringing in scope multiple elements from the same namespaces like in Rust? (Such as `use chess::{Point,Board,Piece}`.)

Comment: No. You can bring all of them or one by one each with a separate statement.

Comment: `using chess::Point, chess::Board, chess::Piece;` is not legal. When `using` specific items, you need a separate `using` statement for each item.

Comment: Does "not legal" mean that it's not guaranteed to be recognized by a compiler?

Comment: Is there room for improving this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [namespace alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace_alias) instead of bringing everything into the scope. Create a shorter alias for `chess`.

```
namespace ch = chess;
// ch::Point, ch::Board, ch::Piece // all are valid.
```

Answer (score 2):

No. But you can bring them all at once, using:

```
using namespace chess;

// then use Point instead of chess::Point, Board instead of chess::Board, etc
```

Comment: I was under the impression that using an entire namespace is bad practice. Does it apply only to the std namespace?

Comment: Well it is definitly bad practice to do it in header files. In source files using namespace std is not recommended. Just be aware that the momemt you do use using namesapce you can get name clashes. In the end (certainly for larger projects) I usually just type the full namespaces everywhere just to keep things maintainable/refactorable and not get surprises when I start using extra libraries

Comment: Something worth noting is that `using` declarations respect scope, so if you only want it for one function you can just put in the function body.